# angular ui.router route parameter conflict in modular app

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I’m building a large angular application and ui router is starting to give me some problems. I hope someone is able to help me out with this.

The application is build as modular as possible. I started out using the modular example by John Papa which you can find in his github repositories. To build the routes I use the code below. This provider builds up all the different route files and gives me the power to set things up per module.

The problem is that I have some routes with a parameter on the root of the application.

url: '/{slug:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+}'

url: '/{slug:[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+}/stores'

etcetera…

Now when I define another route for example /dashboard it takes the route as above.

I’ve been looking in this for some time and know the ui router looks in a specific order of the states to resolve them. So yes the /dashboard url should come before the /{slug: [a-zA-Z0-9-]+} url. However since I’m creating different modules and NOT one routes file this is sort of impossible.

I tried some code in which I check if the url has a parameter on the root to skip it and add it at the end of the loop. However this doesn’t seem to work. When all routes are loaded it still gives me the wrong order in $state.get()

So here is the code that configures the routing

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('components.router')
        .provider('routerHelper', routerHelperProvider);

    routerHelperProvider.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider'];
    /* @ngInject */
    function routerHelperProvider($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
        /* jshint validthis:true */
        var config = {
            docTitle: undefined,
            resolveAlways: {}
        };

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);

        this.configure = function(cfg) {
            angular.extend(config, cfg);
        };

        this.$get = RouterHelper;
        RouterHelper.$inject = ['$location', '$rootScope', '$state', 'logger'];
        /* @ngInject */
        function RouterHelper($location, $rootScope, $state, logger) {
            var handlingStateChangeError = false;
            var hasOtherwise = false;
            var stateCounts = {
                errors: 0,
                changes: 0
            };

            var service = {
                configureStates: configureStates,
                getStates: getStates,
                stateCounts: stateCounts
            };

            init();

            return service;

            ///////////////

            function configureStates(states, otherwisePath) {
                states.forEach(function(state) {
                        state.config.resolve =
                            angular.extend(state.config.resolve || {}, config.resolveAlways);
                        $stateProvider.state(state.state, state.config);
                });
                if (otherwisePath && !hasOtherwise) {
                    hasOtherwise = true;
                    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(otherwisePath);
                }
            }

            function handleRoutingErrors() {
                // Route cancellation:
                // On routing error, go to the dashboard.
                // Provide an exit clause if it tries to do it twice.
                $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError',
                    function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
                        if (handlingStateChangeError) {
                            return;
                        }
                        stateCounts.errors++;
                        handlingStateChangeError = true;
                        var destination = (toState &&
                            (toState.title || toState.name || toState.loadedTemplateUrl)) ||
                            'unknown target';
                        var msg = 'Error routing to ' + destination + '. ' +
                            (error.data || '') + '. <br/>' + (error.statusText || '') +
                            ': ' + (error.status || '');
                        logger.warning(msg, [toState]);
                        $location.path('/');
                    }
                );
            }

            function init() {
                handleRoutingErrors();
                updateDocTitle();
            }

            function getStates() { return $state.get(); }

            function updateDocTitle() {
                $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',
                    function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
                        stateCounts.changes++;
                        handlingStateChangeError = false;
                        var title = config.docTitle + ' ' + (toState.title || '');
                        $rootScope.title = title; // data bind to <title>
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

Here is the function configureStates with the filtering

// States having an optional parameter have to be last so let's check for that

```
    function configureStates(states, otherwisePath) {
        var savedStateForLast;
        states.forEach(function(state) {
            // Check if the root has an optional parameter
            if (state.config.url.match(/^\/\{([a-z_-]+):\[([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\]\+\}/)) {
                console.log('last state: ', state);
                savedStateForLast = state;
            } else {
                console.log('state: ', state);
                state.config.resolve =
                    angular.extend(state.config.resolve || {}, config.resolveAlways);
                $stateProvider.state(state.state, state.config);
            }
        });
        if (angular.isDefined(savedStateForLast)) {
            savedStateForLast.config.resolve =
                angular.extend(savedStateForLast.config.resolve || {}, config.resolveAlways);
            $stateProvider.state(savedStateForLast.state, savedStateForLast.config);   
        }
        if (otherwisePath && !hasOtherwise) {
            hasOtherwise = true;
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(otherwisePath);
        }
    }
```

I really hope someone can help me out here. 
I really would not like to use one file for all my routes.

Comment: Just a comment but - I recently built an angularjs application that was completely modular (we used requirejs) and there was some serious problems with the routing provided by ui routes - we ended up having to build our own router.

Comment: @Michiel have you solved this one?